# ReadEventsAsync got EventHubsExeception(ConsumerDisconnected) intermitently

Tags: azure-eventhub

I am using EventHubConsumerClient.ReadEventsAsync method to read events in eventHub. It works perfectly when I use default eventHub. However, when I route it to a new eventHub I am getting EventHubsExeception(ConsumerDisconnected) from time to time. From the documentation. It says this happen due to `A client was forcefully disconnected from an Event Hub instance. This typically occurs when another consumer with higher OwnerLevel asserts ownership over the partition and consumer group.` I almost got this exception every time. Only a few time it works. Anyone know how to resolve this? Or is there a better way to read message from eventHub? I don't want to use eventProcessorClient since it requires blobContainerClient

for the code, I followed the sample

```
await using var consumerClient = new EventHubConsumerClient(
                    EventHubConsumerClient.DefaultConsumerGroupName,
                    eventHubConnectionString,
                    eventHubName
                    );

await foreach (PartitionEvent partitionEvent in consumerClient.ReadEventsAsync(cancelToken)){
...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow what you're describing.   When you say "the default Event Hub" do you mean consumer group?    Can you share the code where you configure your client, and the details around the exception?

Comment: Speculating based on the message, you'll normally see that only when another consumer/processor is running against the same Event Hub using the same consumer group and is setting the `OwnerLevel` option.   Is there anything else in your environment active?

Comment: As a final note, we strongly discourage using `ReadEventsAsync` in production scenarios.  As the documentation calls out, that method is intended to be used for prototyping and exploring but is not tuned for ensuring fairness of partitions, consistent throughput, or resilience.  Since you mention that you have an aversion to blob storage, you may want to take a look at the `EventProcessor<T>`.

Comment: @JesseSquire Thanks. I have looked at the EventProcessor<T>. But it requires blob storage. I do not want to use that. I want to use my own database which is influxdb. That is why I do not want to use EventProcessor

Comment: `EventProcessor<T>` does not require Blob storage.   You're free to use your choice of storage provider - or to implement without storage altogether if you're willing to trade off collaboration and persistence.   You may be thinking of the `EventProcessorClient` which is an opinionated implementation which does require Blob storage.

Comment: @JesseSquire Thanks. But will it solve the ConsumerDisconnected issue? For my environment variable. I only have eventhubconnectionString.

Comment: I can't say definitively without the additional information that I asked for in my first comment.   The best that I can do with the current context is speculate based on the most common cases - which is my second comment.   If you can share some more detail, I can likely help more.

Comment: @JesseSquire I have updated the code. The error happened at the await foreach line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that you're seeing is very specific to a single scenario: another client has opened an AMQP link to one of the partitions you're reading from and has requested that the Event Hubs service give it exclusive access.  This results in the Event Hubs service terminating your link with an AMQP error code of `Stolen` which the Event Hubs SDK translates into the form that you're seeing.  *([source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/src/Amqp/AmqpError.cs#L195))*

These requests for exclusive access are enforced on a consumer group level.  In your snippet, you're using the default consumer group, which is apparently also used by other consumers.   As a best practice, I'd recommend that you create a unique consumer group for each application that is reading from the Event Hub - unless you specifically want them to interact.

In your case, your client is not requesting exclusive access, so anyone that is will take precedence.  If you were to create a new consumer group and use that to configure your client, I would expect your disconnect errors to stop.